# Filter Sparkdataframe using values from another dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, databricks, sparkr

I have a sparkdataframe that I need to filter based on an ID column which is present in a different dataframe. I am trying to pass this as a list and it doesn't work. Can anyone help ?

head(filter(DF, DF2$user_id))

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that you can consider :

```
library(SparkR)
data("faithful")
faithful[["id"]] <- 1 : nrow(faithful)
df <- SparkR::createDataFrame(faithful)
df_Bool <-  data.frame(1 : nrow(faithful), faithful$waiting > 50)
colnames(df_Bool) <- c("id", "bool1")
df_Bool_Spark <- SparkR::createDataFrame(df_Bool)
df <- SparkR::join(df, df_Bool_Spark, df$id == df_Bool_Spark$id, "left")
df <- drop(df, "id")
as.data.frame(SparkR::filter(df, df$bool1))
```

I used a join operation to merge two data.frame using the id.